# IOS @property, @synthesize memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am developing an IOS application. I did analyze with XCode intruments, If I don't write autorelease then show "potential memory leak" message. Is that an error in the code block below. I was not sure.

```
//TransferList.h
@property (nonatomic,retain) WebServiceAPI *webApi;


//TransferList.m
@implementation TransferList

@synthesize webApi;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webApi = [[[WebServiceAPI alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void)dealloc
{    

    [webApi release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It's not a huge thing but generally you would do `@synthesize webApi = _webApi;` I would get memory leaks sometimes and changing to this way seem to help. I believe in `iOS6` this is automatically done with ARC so you don't have to do `@synthesize` at all.

Comment: Perhaps you can share some details about your web service class. Instruments will show you where the leaked object was allocated, not the root cause of the leak. Have you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" of Xcode's "Product" menu)? Could be a retain cycle (e.g. block variable that references `self`) or something like repeating `NSTimer` retaining web service object.

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that the view controller itself is getting released (i.e. that the view controller, itself, doesn't have retain cycle)? Perhaps put breakpoint or `NSLog` within `dealloc` and make sure it's getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is compiled under MRC (and it obviously is), then without `autorelease` there will be a memory leak. That's absolutely correct.

`alloc` says you want the ownership of the object
Assigning to the property which is `retain` also claims ownership (by the property)
In `dealloc` you are releasing the property (the property won't own the object any more).

If there is no `autorelease`, `viewDidLoad` will never lose ownership of the object and you will have a memory leak because the object won't ever be deallocated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //create the object and get the ownership
    WebServiceAPI *api = [[WebServiceAPI alloc] init];

    //let our property also own this object
    self.webApi = api;

    // I don't want to own the object anymore in this method
    // (of course, using autorelease is simpler)
    [api release];
}

- (void)dealloc {    
    //our property doesn't want to own the object any more
    [webApi release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: He has `autorelease` there already. I suspect retain cycle within his web service class.

Comment: @Sulthan So This is correct or not "self.webApi = [[[WebServiceAPI alloc] init] autorelease];" ? .

Comment: @Rob His code was correct. This answer only explains why `autorelease` or `release` must be there.

Comment: @Sulthan Great! I think I misread his question as "I inserted autorelease and it's still leaking", but I think you're right, that the question was merely "do I really need autorelease?" And, if so, your answer is spot on! +1